# Modular Java Web Application

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, module, osgi, modularization

We have a rich web application based in Java & Spring framework which have many functionalities and classes. recently something sparked in my mind that why not we provide modularity to make it even better.

what I mean by modularity is to provide a section inside the web application that the authenticated user can contribute with us using plugins or extensions. exactly like joomla, wordpress and the other cms's around.

I want to separate each part one to another and while a user upload a plugin, that does not break down the entire system  and core. also I want to provide the plugin/extension tester in the backend that the system won't accept malicious plugins.

The system should be able to uninstall each plugins and extensions without harming the core as well

How do I make this functionalities, and from where we have to start?

Comment: I think you should read about Service Provider Interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say this depends on a couple things. 
One way of achieving this could be having a Modular Framework like either Wicket or Vaadin, use those with OSGi mechanisms like Services provided through blueprint or DS and you should be able to have a fine modular web-application. For example take a look at the [Pax-Wicket](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxwicket/Pax+Wicket) project it does have a sample application that does exactly this.